# why run WAS as service

Tags: windows, websphere

What are the business reasons (advantages/disadvantages) of running a websphere 6.1 App server as a windows service? I mean what are the factors governing this decision?

The other thing I notice is that when I restart the service...and I click something on the admin console, it does n't give me the login page. What is happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give this article a read:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1010_supauth/1010_supauth.html

Can you elaborate on the restarting the service and not receiving the login page issue. I am not sure i understand your query here.

What happens when you click on the console after restarting?

HTH
Manglu

Comment: When I click on a console link (e.g. Enterprise Applications), it just takes me to the page as if the service was not restarted(i.e. the old session was still running)

Comment: It is likely because the LTPA token which is present in the browser as a cookie is still valid. The LTPA tokens are typically valid for 2 hours by default. What happens if you use a new browser instead of using the same browser session?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge - the main reason for choosing to run WebSphere as a Windows Service is that whenever the server goes down for whatever reason, and then is restarted, if not running WebSphere as a service you will need to actually log on to the server and manually start WebSphere. (startServer.bat, startManager.bat, startNode.bat etc).

So for any environment where uptime is an issue on the Windows platform, choose windows service. If you are just installing a development/test environment...not needed.